# Why does host+curl take longer than host alone and curl alone?

Tags: time, curl

I asked this on networkengineering.se, and they suggested I move it here.

---

I tried to test the speed of my website, so I used

`time curl "http://google.com"`

The result ended with

`real   0m15.589s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s`

I tried to see what took so long, so I timed hosts time host google.com

and got

`real   0m0.180s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.004s`

And time curl "http://216.58.217.206"

and got

`real   0m0.163s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s`

0.18 s + 0.16 s (time to lookup DNS **and downloading data**) is much less than 15.58s!!

Why does curl take so long?

---

I ran these commands these a few times in a row, so caching isn't the issue

Comment: What are you actually receiving back when you curl the IP address? I doubt it's the exact same document you'd get when curling google.com

Comment: I ran `curl  "http://google.com" >/tmp/a; curl "http://216.58.219.14" >/tmp/b; diff /tmp/b  /tmp/a`

Comment: @Wesley returned nothing

Answer (score 0):

You could run `curl -v "http://google.com"` for a more verbose output that might allow you to see where the delay occurs. 15 seconds is long enough for there to be a visible wait at some point.

Comment: It's between "Rebuilt URL to: http://google.com/" and "Trying 216.58.219.14..."

Comment: I don't see a "Rebuilt URL..." line at all when I try, and am not actually sure what that means; can't find it in the docs anywhere. What version of curl is that (`curl -V`)?

Comment: curl 7.45.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.45.0 GnuTLS/3.3.18 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 libssh2/1.5.0 nghttp2/1.5.0 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets